# Картины пишут или рисуют? И почему - живопись?

Tags: этимология, грамотная-речь

Чаще по отношению к картинам говорят, что художники их пишут, но по факту они их рисуют. Тут та же ситуация, что с кораблями, которые по морской терминологии ходят, но по факту - плавают. Так вот, будет ли ошибкой сказать, что картину рисуют, а не пишут? И еще интересно было бы узнать этимологию слова "живопись", особенно первого корня "-жив" (живые пишут или пишут живое?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Картины, действительно, чаще пишут, а не рисуют, что связано с этимологией этих слов.

Слово «рисовать»  появилось в русском языке в самом начале 18 века, в словарях отмечено с 1731 года. Оно заимствовано из западноевропейских языков, где его  старшим  значением было «чертить, вырезать, царапать». Рисовать – это изображать, воспроизводить предметы на плоскости (карандашом, пером, углем, красками).

Слово писать известно с 11 века,  но его значение было  ближе к современному понятию «изображать красками». Достаточно вспомнить, что слова «пестрый" и «писать/пестрить»  имеют одну о.-с. основу.

Согласно словарям, живописью называют изобразительное искусство, воспроизводящее предметы и явления реального мира с помощью красок.  Название является калькой с греческого языка. Дело в том, что в античном мире  особенно ценилась способность нарисовать предмет «как в жизни». Не случайно бытовали легенды об умении художника так нарисовать виноград, что птицы прилетали его клевать.

Answer (score 2):

ЖИВОПИСЬ- слово образовано по методу кальки с греческого zographia. http://terme.ru/dictionary/192/word/zhivopis

Русское слово живопись указывает на реализм этого искусства в эпоху барокко, когда в России начали писать картины в западном стиле, преимущественно масляными красками. В иконописи употребляется глагол «писа́ть», так же как в греческом языке. В то же время «живописать» может быть понято как энергичная, своеобразная манера писать, т. е. и как своего рода письменность.
В связи живописи с письменностью семиотики видят и определённую манеру создавать знаки.
История живописи развивается и блуждает именно в этих двух смыслах: в изобразительности, реалистичности и — знаковости: от иконы (образ) к абстракции.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, слово "рисовать" появилось позднее живописи.

Answer (score 0):

Художники пишут, особенно это полезно узнать школьникам при описывании картины. Художник написал картину а не нарисовал.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]